# strip a verbose python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a verbose python regex string  (with lots of whitespace and comments) that I'd like to convert to "normal" style (for export to javascript). In particular, I need this to be quite reliable. If there's any demonstrably correct way to do this, it's what I want. For example, a naive implementation would destroy a regex like `r' \# # A literal hash character'`, which is not OK.

The best way to do this would be to coerce the python re module to give me back a non-verbose representation of my regex, but I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Apparently someone did this, but it's in JavaScript http://blog.mackerron.com/2010/08/08/extended-multi-line-js-regexps/

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. Just remove before a  \n but before a #, and remove anything that matches \w but not \\\w.

Comment: Unfortunately, it converts a custom verbose regex syntax to JS regex syntax, which isn't quite the same as converting Python verbose regex syntax to Python non-verbose regex syntax… but you could definitely use that code as a model for writing your own Python equivalent, if you can't find one

Comment: @Linuxios: You've already thought of two edge cases, and I doubt you've thought of them all. Bugs lie down this path, and it's why I don't want to go there.

Comment: @bukzor: I agree that bugs lie down this path. As someone said "If you use regular expressions to solve a problem, you have two problems." If you try to use regexes to port regexes to another language's regexes, you've got more problems than I care to count. :).

Comment: @Linuxios Yes a solution that doesn't use regexes (or hand-crafted string parsing for that matter) is preferable.

Comment: @bukzor: Unfortunately, RegexObject's `pattern` returns the *exact* string you pass in. So there's nothing in `re` to help.

Comment: Do you want to automate the process to transform many regexes , or do you need to transform a limited number of regexes ? There are other manners to write the patterns of regexes that I like more than the VERBOSE format. My opinion is that if you haven't a lot of transformations to do, you will be faster to do it manually than crafting a program during days. If the pattern is under the VERBOSE format, it facilitates such a transformation. Could you give an exemple of a pattern you would like to transform, please.

Comment: Or you could use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/). Performance is the same as native JS regex.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, Qtax, Linuxios, please consider posting your answers as answers instead of as comments.

Comment: IIRC, the `regex` module (available on PyPI, and being gradually groomed to replace `re` as the standard in Python 3.something) is 99%+ compatible with `re`, was written from scratch to be cleaner and easier to work with, and has a pure-Python implementation. So, it might be a lot easier to start there, than to either with `re` or from ground up.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you only need to address these two issues to strip a verbose regex:

1. delete comments to the end of line
2. delete unescaped whitespace

try this, which chains the 2 with separate regex substitutions:

```
import re

def unverbosify_regex_simple(verbose):
    WS_RX = r'(?<!\\)((\\{2})*)\s+'
    CM_RX = r'(?m)(?<!\\)((\\{2})*)#.*$'

    return re.sub(WS_RX, "\\1", re.sub(CM_RX, "\\1", verbose))
```

The above is a simplified version that leaves escaped spaces as-is.  The resulting output will be a little harder to read but should work for regex platforms.

Alternatively, for a slightly more complex answer that "unescapes" spaces (i.e., '\ ' => ' ') and returns what I think most people would expect:

```
import re

def unverbosify_regex(verbose):
    CM1_RX = r'(?m)(?<!\\)((\\{2})*)#.*$'
    CM2_RX = r'(\\)?((\\{2})*)(#)'
    WS_RX  = r'(\\)?((\\{2})*)(\s)\s*'

    def strip_escapes(match):
        ## if even slashes: delete space and retain slashes
        if match.group(1) is None:
            return match.group(2)

        ## if number of slashes is odd: delete slash and keep space (or 'comment')
        elif match.group(1) == '\\':
            return match.group(2) + match.group(4)

        ## error
        else:
            raise Exception

    not_verbose_regex = re.sub(WS_RX, strip_escapes,
                          re.sub(CM2_RX, strip_escapes,
                            re.sub(CM1_RX, "\\1", verbose)))

    return not_verbose_regex
```

**UPDATE:** added comments to explain even v. odd slash counting. Fixed first group in CM_RX to retain full 'comment' if slash count is odd.

**UPDATE 2:** Fixed comments regex, which was not dealing with escaped hashes properly.  Should handle both "\# #escaped hash" as well as "# comment with \# escaped hash" and "\\# comment"

**UPDATE 3:** Added a simplified version that doesn't clean up escaped spaces.

**UPDATE 4:** Further simplification to eliminate variable-length negative lookbehind (and reverse/reverse trick)

Comment: To improve your answer, you can also convert `'\ '` to `' '`, `'\# '` to `'#'`.

Comment: Point 2 should be amended to state, "except when occurring in sets" — which makes the implementation much more complex.

Comment: How come all of these are optional? `(\\{2})*(\\)?` This seems to express "the number of slashes is either even or odd"... The double-reverse is a funny workaround for the lack of variable-length look behind. Any way around that? It makes your regexen twice as hard to evaluate.

Comment: The `(?m)` is the multiline flag. These are commonly put at the beginning of the regex, or even more commonly as the `flags` argument to `re.compile`. I note that `re.sub` also takes a flags argument.

Comment: buzkor: you are exactly correct.  If the space is preceded by an odd number of slashes, then we know it is an escaped space and the space should be retained but one of the slashes should be removed. If it is preceded by an even number of slashes, then it is a verbose space (preceded by one or more slashes) and the space should be deleted.

Comment: re variable-length look behind: python currently supports this, so we have to use a reverse-lookahead trick. I believe some sort of variable look ahead or behind is required to handle the possibility of escaped slashes. It may be a very unlikely edge-case, though, so you can probably get by with a simplified version that drops the reverse + look-ahead and you just live with the fact that it will be incorrect for cases like r"""\\\\ blah"""

Comment: re multiline -- yes, "(?m)" is just the multiline flag. I'm a perl guy where the flags come at the end, but moving it to the beginning is fine too.  You can also specify the flags in the re.sub or re.compile, though I generally don't like that as it requires your compile or sub statement to "understand" the needs of your regex -- I prefer to keep the regex self-contained.  Makes it easier to find/fix bugs later :)

Comment: @dpkp The easiest way to fix regex bugs is to remove the regexes from your code :P  I believe this is a counter-example for your code: "\# # escaped hash"

Comment: @buzkor well, you're the one with all the regexs in your code :P  I've gone back and thought about the escaped hash issue and realized that I actually overcomplicated the comments regex.  Fixed above.  This passes your test as well as the slight (albeit unlikely) variant "blah # comment with \# an escaped hash"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24781/discussion-between-dpkp-and-bukzor)